# Sorting array of object javascript / typescript on firestore timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have below array structure

```
[
  {
    "id": "8gFUT6neK2I91HIVkFfy",
    "element": {
      "id": "8gFUT6neK2I91HIVkFfy",
      "archived": false,
      "updatedOn": {
        "seconds": 1538653447,
        "nanoseconds": 836000000
      }
    },
    "groupBy": "pr"
  },
  {
    "id": "9jHfOD8ZIAOX4fE1KUQc",
    "element": {
      "id": "9jHfOD8ZIAOX4fE1KUQc",
      "archiveDate": {
        "seconds": 1539250407,
        "nanoseconds": 62000000
      },
      "archived": false,
      "updatedOn": {
        "seconds": 1538655984,
        "nanoseconds": 878000000
      }
    },
    "groupBy": "pr"
  },
  {
    "id": "CeNP27551idLysSJOd5H",
    "element": {
      "id": "CeNP27551idLysSJOd5H",
      "archiveDate": {
        "seconds": 1539248724,
        "nanoseconds": 714000000
      },
      "archived": false,
      "updatedOn": {
        "seconds": 1538651075,
        "nanoseconds": 235000000
      }
    },
    "groupBy": "pr"
  },
  {
    "id": "Epd2PVKyUeAmrzBT3ZHT",
    "element": {
      "id": "Epd2PVKyUeAmrzBT3ZHT",
      "archiveDate": {
        "seconds": 1539248726,
        "nanoseconds": 226000000
      },
      "archived": false,
      "updatedOn": {
        "seconds": 1538740476,
        "nanoseconds": 979000000
      }
    },
    "groupBy": "pr"
  }
]
```

and below code to sort

Sample JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/68wvebpz/

```
 let sortedData = this.arraydata.sort((a:any, b:any) => { return Number(new Date(b.element.date).getTime()) - Number(new Date(a.element.date).getTime()) })
```

This does not make any effect.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. And also, I don't know what you're doing, but you can simply do `(a, b) => b.element.date - a.element.date`.

Comment: .sort method doesnt mutate the array, it returns a new one. Might the problem be that you forgot to assign the result to this.arraydata? (it does mutate, was mistaken)

Comment: I have tried many variation like simply a.element.date, new date(a.element.data) then trying Number(new date(a.element.date), but nothing working

Comment: Can you post your example code with data?

Comment: @askerovlab No [sort mutates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if you want to make a new array you can do: `this.arraydata = this.arraydata.slice().sort(...`

Comment: It should have an effect. Please provide the code with which we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @HMR, yes, my mistake. Not ideal though

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/68wvebpz/

Comment: You're trying to substract an object from another. No wonder it doesn't work. use `seconds` or `nanoseconds` (or a combination of both), since `sort` callback is supposed to return a number.

Comment: Its timestamp coming from firestore database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems that we need to fix:

1. Your `updatedOn` object is not something that can be converted to a date. You need to do extra work.
2. JavaScript doesn't support nanoseconds, only milliseconds. You will therefore need to divide that number by a million.
3. By using `getTime` for the comparison, you're actually discarding the milliseconds - that function returns seconds.

To fix the first two, use this function:

```
function objToDate(obj) {
  let result = new Date(0);
  result.setSeconds(obj.seconds);
  result.setMilliseconds(obj.nanoseconds/1000000);
  console.log('With nano', result);
  return result;
}
```

This creates a new date and then sets the seconds and milliseconds. This gives you dates in October 2018 when I use your test data.

Then, to compare them and fix the remaining problems, use this (much simpler) form:

```
let sortedData = data.sort((a:any, b:any) => { 
  let bd = objToDate(b.element.updatedOn);
  let ad = objToDate(a.element.updatedOn);
  return ad - bd
});
```

That should do it.

To reverse the sort order, just use the less-than operator:

```
  return bd - ad
```

Comment: I can see the objToDate is converting the seconds and nanoseconds to date, but it is not sorting

Comment: Sure it is. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cobusk/68wvebpz/3/
I get them in the order "CeNP27551idLysSJOd5H", "8gFUT6neK2I91HIVkFfy", "9jHfOD8ZIAOX4fE1KUQc", "Epd2PVKyUeAmrzBT3ZHT". That's in ascending order.

Comment: aah, I had two tab with differnet dataset and I was looking at different tab... its working, just one thing, when I applied this sort to other dataset it was saying ''Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number' ,...... though when i gave a minues (-) instead of greater than symbol, it is working,, I googed some, but could not understand why it is not working at diff dataset, thoughg structure is same

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Actually, I realise that you're correct about the compare function - it returns a number, where >0 means greater than, <0 means less than and 0 means equal. You can just subtract the dates. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I updated the answer. Please remember to accept it if it helped you.

Comment: Yep, that helped, but could you please let me understand why > is working for one dateset where as not for other dataset

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam That's a result of JavaScript's relaxed type rules. The value `true` is evaluated as 1 and `false` as zero. So when I compared, I was in effect returning ones and zeros, which will work for the sort function. But not -1, which means the left-hand value is less than the right-hand value. I'm not sure if that would have affected the sort in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like this:

```
var array = [
{id: 1, name:'name1', date: 'Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM'},
{id: 2, name:'name2', date: 'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM'}
];

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
}))
```